# How to skip sorted part of an array in a sorting program if my array is already partly sorted

Tags: arrays, sorting, fortran, bubble-sort, fortran90

So we were taught bubble sort in our class and I have this code

```
!Sorting n real numbers 
program bubblesort
implicit none   
integer::i,j,n
integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::A 
write(*,*)"Enter the number of elements"
read(*,*)n
allocate (A(n))
write(*,*)"Enter the numbers"
read(*,*)(A(i),i=1,n)
do while (n>1)
    do i=1,n-1
        if(A(i) > A(i+1)) then
            j = A(i)
            A(i) = A(i+1)
            A(i+1) = j
        endif
    enddo
    n = n-1
enddo   
write(*,*)"The sorted array is - ",A
end program
```

now my professor asked me to modify it in a way that if part of the given array to be sorted is already in the correct place then we should skip that part, for example say my array is `5 3 1 2 4 6 7 8`, here `6 7 8` are in the correct place so how can we write a program such that it automatically skips these last 3 elements.

I've looked everywhere online but I couldn't find how it optimize bubble sort in this way, I could only find ways to check if the entire array is sorted and then how to end the sorting when that happens.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: OK, what is the information that you can give to your program? What is the information about the partially sorted array you have? Do you know the indexes that are sorted? Or the values? Or what exactly? How shall the input look like? You can always just run the same algorithm on a subarray, that is trivial. You should first make a sorting subroutine. Do not have everything in the main program.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава So I'm learning fortran for my physics class and my prof said that sometimes the data we get is "naturally partly sorted" so all information that I have is that the data has some elements that are already in the correct place. I do not know the index or the values of those elements. He told us to do this so that we can save some processor cycles which will be good when we get to big data. About subroutines, yes I know how to do that now but sorting was done in the introduction part and so I did it in the main program back then, I just added that code here for reference.

Comment: With a subroutine, once you know what part is not sorted, you can just call the subroutine on the relevant subarray.

Comment: Suppose that at the end of the first pass the part-sorted array is `5 3 1 2 4 6 7 8`.  Study carefully what happens in the second pass; pay particular attention to the positions of the last pair of elements which are swapped.  And don't forget that after `n` passes the `n` largest elements are already in their right locations.

Comment: I would just point out, even if likely needlessly, that bubble sort algorithm is slow and inadequate for production sorting when we core about performance. It is used to teach basic programming. The [Shellsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellsort) is a very simple modification, which is, however, much faster and can be used for real-world purposes.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Sorry if this is a stupid question but how will I know what part is not sorted using a subroutine? Do you mean that I should run it once in the subroutine and if the last n pairs are not swapped then I should skip those while running again? 
Also I think is that what you also meant @HighPerformanceMark?

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Yes I am aware that bubble sort is bad for real life uses but this is what was asked of us, but if this is done better in some other method then please say so that will work too! (I have some doubts that my prof is actually using this to get us to discover some other algorithm(s))

Comment: @IgnisVizsla That is not a stupid question at all! You either do know that because you know where the data come from, or you do not and you have to follow the advice by HighPerformanceMark.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава thanks! I'll try to follow this and will let both of you know if it worked. I'm hoping it does

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава I was able to solve this! I have added what I did as an answer as I was able to solve this
Thanks to you for all the help!

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  I was able to solve this! I have added what I did as an answer as I was able to solve this. Thanks to you for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve this using 2 different subroutines, one is for the first check which goes through the array and checks how many elements at the end do not need further sorting and then I used another subroutine for the rest of the bubble sort runs

```
!This is the first run of bubble sort to know the range 
subroutine Bubtest(n,A,k)
implicit none
integer::i,j,k,n,A(8)
do i=1,n-1
    if(A(i) > A(i+1)) then
        j = A(i)
        A(i) = A(i+1)
        A(i+1) = j
        k = i
    endif
enddo
k = k+1
end subroutine
```

This is the first subroutine which determines k, which finds the reduced range

```
!This is the main bubble sort subroutine
subroutine sortBub(k, A)
implicit none
integer::i,j,k,A(8)
do while (k>1)
    do i=1,k-1
        if(A(i) > A(i+1)) then
            j = A(i)
            A(i) = A(i+1)
            A(i+1) = j
        endif
    enddo
    k = k-1
enddo
end subroutine
```

And this is for the regular bubble sort using the reduced range in the array

In my main program I just call these two consecutively